# Series isolated DC-DC converters fed by different PV sources

Tags: dc-dc-converter, series

I would like to have more detail about the description given by Vicor application note http://cdn.vicorpower.com/documents/application_notes/an1_high-vout.pdf:

> In a series array, the positive output of each module requires a series diode (D1 and D2) to prevent the array from being back-driven by load capacitance during turn-off, and to assure proper operation during start-up and dynamic loading. This diode must have a reverse voltage rating greater than the array’s output voltage and a forward current rating greater than the array’s maximum load current.
>   In all configurations, diodes D3 and D4 prevent the output from going negative if only one converter is operational.

This is said because I managed to simulate two distributed DC-DC converters fed by different PV panels and if one converter is operated the diode (D3 or D4) will be reverse biased and prevent the current of the other converter to flow.

Comment: Have you tried contacting them with specific questions. Saying you would like more detail requires telepathy to make an answer.

Comment: Not yet, but if someone gives me more explanation about the role of the diodes D3 and D4 I would be deeply grateful!

Answer (score 1):

OK I understand. Try this: -

[image]

The two outputs are wired in series - this means current flow is determined by the weakest output without D3 or D4 being present. If one of the converters is powered down then its output impedance might rise to any value and I've made a guess at 1 kohm although realistically it could be between 10 ohms and several M ohms.

The diodes bypass the this output impedance and the small price to pay is one diode drop.

Comment: Ok!, but what happens if there are two different PV panels tied instead of a constant Vin?

Comment: My picture above shows the worst case scenario of seperate Vins with one of them not present.

Comment: But PV panels have a diff behavior as a simple battery, so what happens if I put different current sources instead of Vins?

Comment: Who can tell but this hasn't anything to do with the function of D3 or D4.

Comment: The problem was when I started to model this structure, the mppt of the first brick didn't work, the duty cycle was always 0% on the contrary, the mppt of second brick was fine! I am now trying to understand where does the problem come from?

Comment: Doesn't sound like an output diode problem.

Comment: The problem comes from the double use of the same CMEX S-function binary code by which I write the algorithm. +1